# Pricerr theme and Paypal Chained Adaptive

Tags: paypal

I am seeking help setting up Paypal gateway for 2 simultaneous payments, 15% to website owner & 85% to service seller.

I have set up a wordpres theme called Pricerr, published a product, and completed all the payment gateway details for Paypal. I believe that I have filled in ALL the fields on the PricerrTheme - Payment Methods form correctly.

For every purchase, I want the website to get 15% (into Paypal business account) of the fee and the service supplier to get 85%, simultaneously.

I believe this means the payment must be adaptive.

When I set up the Payment gateway details as standard, the whole fee gets paid to the website. This transaction works as far as Paypal is concerned.

When I however make it an Adaptive payment, I get the below error, no matter what I do.

You can test the purchase if you like (I have one service that costs 50 cents, and I will repay anyone the 50 cents if they purchase the service while testing the gateway.

The error message is below.

Please help me fix the Paypal payment gateway. I want a simultaneous payment split in two, like below, if possible.

Buyer ===> 15% to website
===> 85% to seller

```
ERROR
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] => ns3:FaultMessage
[attributes] => Array
(
[xmlns:ns3] => http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common
[xmlns:ns2] => http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap
)

[0] => Array
(
[name] => responseEnvelope
[0] => Array
(
[name] => timestamp
[value] => 2015-09-04T17:13:04.118-07:00
)

[1] => Array
(
[name] => ack
[value] => Failure
)

[2] => Array
(
[name] => correlationId
[value] => d4103492da29a
)

[3] => Array
(
[name] => build
[value] => 17820627
)

)

[1] => Array
(
[name] => error
[0] => Array
(
[name] => errorId
[value] => 550001
)

[1] => Array
(
[name] => domain
[value] => PLATFORM
)

[2] => Array
(
[name] => subdomain
[value] => Application
)

[3] => Array
(
[name] => severity
[value] => Error
)

[4] => Array
(
[name] => category
[value] => Application
)

[5] => Array
(
[name] => message
[value] => User is not allowed to perform this action
)

)

)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you business account is not verified, please verify the account firstly, then try to call API again.
How to verify a PayPal account: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ444&m=HTQ

Comment: You are welcome ! In your adaptive payment app, you didn't enable Chained payments option, so you can't call PAY API with actionType=PAY_PRIMARY(it's a chained payment type). You can firstly call a simple parallel payment to check whether it's worked or not. refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: okay, well I did that. When I set it to parallel payment, it worked, except that the percentages were wrong. But atleast I didn't get an error message. But as soon as I set it as chained, the dreaded error message returned.

Comment: In your adaptive payment app, you didn't enable chained payment, so you get error message when you use chained payment in script. I suggest you can submit a new app and enable chained payment in this new app.

Comment: I have selected chained payment but I still get the same error.

Comment: yes, I see you submit a new application with chained payment enable, it's approved at yesterday. could you try your API request again ? if still has issue, share the detail API response. Thanks 1